# Why some jsfiddle examples work without having external url

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have noticed that on some jsfiddle.net examples there are no external links, but it still works.

But when I create my jsfiddle sample it won't work without external url packages.

For example jsfiddle.net/afm7rhsw/ link has angularjs working on it, but there is no any external package to it.

Couldn't figure out, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select common libraries to use with your fiddle via the drop down in the `JavaScript` section. See attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: and where is it showing this button? Do i need to create an account in order to see?

Comment: @INgeeg What do you mean? JSFiddle adds the library automatically if it is selected from the `Frameworks & Extensions` drop down. If you want to see where it is pulling it in from you could always look in your browsers developer console. But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I got it. I just had never noticed that "Javascript" button. Thank you so so much